# Some 2D Java Code Trouble

Tags: java, swing, jframe, 2d

I'm trying to start a bit of 2d code and I have this much so far. It should just make a window appear but when I run it (in debug) I get an error saying source not found? Anyone see what I'm missing?

```
    package game;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Dimension;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 160;
public static final int HEIGHT= WIDTH/12*9;
public static final int SCALE=3;
public static final String NAME = "My Game";

private JFrame frame;
public boolean running=false;

public Game()
{
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

    frame = new JFrame(NAME);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocation(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized void start() 
    {
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
    }

public synchronized void stop() 
    {
    running =false;
    }

public void run() 
    {
    while(running)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    }

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new Game().start();

}


 }
```

I was working from a few tutorials to get this and I went through the code myself a few times but I cant spot whats wrong. :(

Comment: Please include the full error and stack trace. I just get an error at `frame.setLocation(null)`, and if I remove that it runs fine, showing an empty frame and printing "Hello" in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah that worked when I removed that line too, but I thought it had to be included. The frame and "hello" loop was expected.

Comment: yeah that was it thanks :) sorry I start to miss these things when I've been staring at it too long.

Comment: Maybe you meant `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` which perfectly works and sets the frame's location centered in the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
frame.setLocation(null);
```

The parameter provided to [`setLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28java.awt.Point%29) must not be null. If you do not need to set the location of the frame, don't call the method. By default, the frame is placed in the upper-left corner of the screen.

Comment: Alternatively, invoking `setLocationByPlatform(true)` right before opening the `Frame` allows a system-specific default location.